# Logstash error: open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml: permission denied

Tags: docker, linux, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a logging repo that contains filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch, kibana and a setup file, it is running normally on different servers using dockers, but now i am trying to build it on a new server but it didn't work using Debian11.
When i run **docker compose logs -f setup** I got the following **Could not resolve host. Is Elasticsearch running?** and when I run **docker-compose up** I got the following **Logstash error: open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml: permission denied**
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more details such as the owner of the file `/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml`? Are you running docker-compose as root user or any other user?

Comment: @Samit How can i check that and how can i change the permission?

Comment: @Samit I don't have the following directory, i am using docker, i think it is installed inside docker